# How can I convert this innerhtml loop to a innertext one because XSS vulnerabilities?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, innerhtml

I need to convert this loop to innertext with the dynamically added content how can I do that I looked on the internet but could'nt find anything?

```
function showMessages(messages) {

    jsonMessages.innerHTML = "<tr><th>Naam</th><th>Bericht</th><th>Datum</th></tr>";

        messages.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.created_at > b.created_at ? 1 : -1;
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            jsonMessages.innerHTML +=  `<tr><td>${messages[i].user_id}</td><td>${messages[i].content.replace(/</g,"&lt;")}</td><td>${messages[i].created_at}</td></tr>`;
        }
    console.log(messages);
}
```

Comment: change `.innerHTML` to `.innerText`? Note though that will make it so the html will not render as html elements, you will just have displayed a html string. Are you sure you have to change it to innerText?

Comment: that doesn't work with the dynamic added <tr><td></td><td>

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: because it is not rendering like elements but like text

Comment: Yes that is exactly how `innerText` works, it is for setting text not html, that is what `innerHTML` is for. Why do you think you need to change it to `innerText`?

Comment: XSS vulnerabilities

Comment: Update your question to mention that, as that makes it easier to understand what you are needing.

Comment: Just create elementsseperately and use innertext to add texts. It takes time... dont be lazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function showMessages(messages) {

    jsonMessages.innerHTML = "<tr><th>Naam</th><th>Bericht</th><th>Datum</th></tr>";

        messages.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.created_at > b.created_at ? 1 : -1;
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

           var mainTr = document.createElement('tr');
           var td1 = document.createElement('td').appendChild(document.createTextNode(messages[i].user_id));
           var td2 = document.createElement('td').appendChild(document.createTextNode(messages[i].content.replace(/</g,"&lt;")));;
           var td3 = document.createElement('td').appendChild(document.createTextNode(messages[i].created_at));

           mainTr.appendChild(td1);
           mainTr.appendChild(td2);
           mainTr.appendChild(td3);

           jsonMessages.appendChild(mainTr);

        }
    console.log(messages);
}
```

Comment: `appendChild` returns the appended child not the original element. So  your calls are setting `td1`,`td2`,`td3` to the respective text nodes instead of the `<td>` elements.

Answer (score 3):

To change your code to prevent xss by using `innerText` instead of arbitrarily setting `innerHTML` to some unknown code you will need to create elements themselves first then set their content

For instance

```
//create a tr element
tr = document.createElement('tr');
//create new cell for above tr
td = tr.insertCell();
td.innerText = messages[i].user_id;
```

You would do this for the all elements that would have dynamic content. So in your case you could do the following

```
for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  let userIdCell = tr.insertCell();
  let contentCell = tr.insertCell();
  let dateCell = tr.insertCell();
  userIdCell.innerText = messages[i].user_id;
  contentCell = messages[i].content;
  dateCell = messages[i].created_at;

  //finally add it to your table
  jsonMessages.appendChild(tr);
}
```

There are other routes that do the same thing, like putting a blank string of your html structure into an element then select the elements and set them:

```
let tr = document.createElement('tr');
tr.innerHTML = `<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>`;
//first td child
tr.children[0] = messages[i].user_id;
//second td child
tr.children[1] = messages[i].content;
//third td child
tr.children[2] = messages[i].created_id;
```

It all just depends on your personal preference. The main point is to just create the elements first then set their innerText property instead of setting the whole html as one.